# What is a good tool for producing animated sprites?

Tags: tools, sprites, animation

Has anyone come across a software package that allows you to build animations in a similar way to how you can in Flash (i.e. using techniques such as tweens & bones & easings, etc) and then have the result exported as a sprite sheet?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can use Flash, a 3D Tool or even Photoshops animation feature. Then render the frames to images and combine them to a sprite-sheet.

[ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) has a great tool for that purpose called *montage*.
Here's a [blog post](http://www.bensnider.com/imagemagick-split-and-join-a-sprite-sheet.html) explaining how to use it to create a sprite sheet.

Comment: Is there *anything* ImageMagick can't do? :)

Comment: I haven't gotten it to make me coffee in the morning yet...

Answer (score 6):

While those techniques work well for vector graphics, they don't translate well to pixel art. Sprites don't tend to handle rotation or scaling without distortion, so hand editing is essential.

Two products worth looking into for spriting are Cosmigo's [ProMotion](http://www.cosmigo.com/promotion/index.php) and [GraphicsGale](http://www.humanbalance.net/gale/us/). Onion skinning and other features are available. But if you want clean pixel art, automation isn't going to do the job.

edit: Okay, my brain is tired. A cup of coffee later and I realize what you're looking for. You could try out [SynFig](http://www.synfig.org/), which looks like it might be adaptable to your needs :)

Answer (score 2):

The way we make our animated sprites is by rendering out frames from a 3D modeling program.

Comment: Who is "we"? Sounds like a good way to go.

Answer (score 2):

I've been using [Texture Packer](http://www.texturepacker.com/) to create sprites for my iPhone game. It's similar to [Zwoptex](http://zwoptexapp.com/) but has a free version. I'm porting a game originally developed in Flash, so I'm simply exporting each frame of the MovieClip to png and then importing those images in Texture Packer.

Answer (score 2):

I use Gamedev Animation Studio for create animation. It can export animated images into C# classes which i instantly include into my project

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty Sure you can use Flash and go file > export movie> png sequence. Then combine the pngs using Photoshop to make your sprite sheet. Also check out the animation features of fireworks.

Answer (score 1):

[ToonBoom studio](http://www.toonboom.com/products/toonBoomStudio/) is a flash like  animation tool and can export sprite sheets.

Answer (score 1):

Use gimp and its plugin called sprite sheet

Comment: Some links and more detailed description would make this a better answer.