# What do you use to create sprite graphics?

Tags: graphics, tools

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What tools do you use for 2D art/sprite creation?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/what-tools-do-you-use-for-2d-art-sprite-creation)

What do you folks suggest for creating sprite graphics and sprite sheets?

I fiddle with [pixelformer](http://www.qualibyte.com/pixelformer/) and [tilestudio](http://tilestudio.sourceforge.net/).

Pixelfromer has a kicken interface, it is quick and easy to make graphics, but a bit cumbersom if you want to make a spritemap.
Tile Studio is a interesting mix or tiles and maps, but it is a bit buggy and basic.

The Adobe series, just don't really seem to handle tiny graphics well.

(there is a [previous posting](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/what-tools-do-you-use-for-2d-art-sprite-creation) of this question existing,  but it is a year old and I was hoping for further/updated input from the community)

Comment: If you wanted to contribute to that question with your answer, just add what you use to the question.  It'll bump it.  The goal of these sites is to be the canonical place to find the answer to questions, and making duplicates to look for "newer information" is noise from the POV of people searching.  Also, you shouldn't ask a question that's "I use X for Y, what do you use".  See [this portion of the faq](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/faq#dontask)).  Closing as a duplicate.

Comment: A years time can contribute greatly to the tools that are on the internet, asking after that time is not a waste of space or time. The past post is deep gone and would never be seen to see responses to my question. I was posting the things I use hoping for plausible alternatives of the same scope.