# What's the best 2D animator?

Tags: 2d, animation, sprites

What's the best 2D animator for creating sprite sheet animations for a game? Are there any that match this criteria?

- Cutout animation (I don't want to have to draw every frame)
- Exporting to images
- Simple and lightweight (I don't want something that bogs down my machine and I'm not doing a 2d animated movie, I just want to animate a characters walk/jump cycle)
- Cheap or Free

Preferable it would be opensource, but I'm willing to pay for a good piece of software under $50 dollars

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is a good tool for producing animated sprites?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/335/what-is-a-good-tool-for-producing-animated-sprites)

Comment: Also: [What tools do you use for 2D art/sprite creation?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1059/what-tools-do-you-use-for-2d-art-sprite-creation?lq=1) and [Tool for creating Spritesheet?](http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4387/tool-for-creating-spritesheet-and-tips?rq=1)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a piece of software currently in beta called Spriter that had an excellent previous run, and is now forging on ahead for even more features/usability. If I recall correctly, I paid $20 for it in the kickstarter, but you can still buy it and get instant access to the beta. You can find it [here](http://brashmonkey.com/spriter.htm).

Comment: Looks good, but the beta is still in heavy development. The full version looks good though.

Comment: Indeed it is, but it already functions extremely well. I'd say probably well enough for your uses.