# What are the advantages of a sprite sheet over an image sequence/flash timeline?

Tags: 2d, graphics, flash, spritesheet

I've noticed sprite sheets are used more and more in Flash games and I don't fully understand what are the advantages over an image sequence/flash timeline - MovieClip.

I've read this related question:
[2D graphics - why use spritesheets?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/7069/2d-graphics-why-use-spritesheets) 
and that makes sense for hardware accelerated games, but that's not the case for
flash yet.

Any Flash Player specific insights ?

Comment: I don't know if there's any real technical advantage, but if I were to start making a flash game, I'd probably go with a sprite sheet because I'm more familiar with that approach than flash timelines..

Comment: Just because Flash is not hardware accelerated yet does not mean that it isnt processing things in the same way... Remember that graphics can be done on a CPU, the GPU was just made specifically to do it (And alot of other things as of late, hehe)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Some popular flash game engines (eg. [flixel](http://flixel.org/)) use sprite-sheets for sprite-animations. This is mainly because they also implemented a bitmap-based rendering engine which doesn't use the native flash display-classes like "Sprite", "MovieClip" for each object but rather a big bitmap-image where stuff is drawn onto using pixel-operations.
Using a bitmap-based approach (i.e. Spritesheet) for a bitmap-based rendering engine is the most efficient thing to do.

This [question](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/1081/rendering-performance-for-flash-games) covers some of the different rendering-methods.

Answer (score 5):

Don't think there is a huge advantage to using one or the other, but it makes porting your game/graphics a lot easier, as any platform can use spritesheets.  If you are doing a strict flash game, probably comes down to preference/quickness.