# I am looking for a simple tutorial for sprite animation in android

Tags: android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What's the best way to create animations when doing Android development?](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/18003/whats-the-best-way-to-create-animations-when-doing-android-development)

I saw a couple of them on the internet but they are beyond my level of understanding ...I need to start with basics in a simpler way if possible...can anyone guide me to some good online resources for this

Answer (score 0):

This link might help you: http://www.droidnova.com/2d-sprite-animation-in-android,471.html

A quick google on "Sprite animation android" would yield alot of nice answers.

However, since you mentioned that most were beyond your level of understanding, I suggest you look at the following article on sprites first: http://www.rpgrevolution.com/tutorial/rough-guide-to-sprite-animation_107.html

In short, the computer would divide a sprite sheet into many frames, and cycle through the frames repeatedly to simulate an animation effect.

The best way is to simply follow through a tutorial. You might not understand it at first, but copying and pasting codes helps in understanding as well.

Cheers!