# Create sprite sheet (texture atlas) from video with alpha

Tags: spritesheet

What's the best way to make a sprite sheet (texture atlas) from a video?

In my case, I have videos of animated character expressions (e.g., smiling, frowning, sad, excited), which I intend to use as frames on quads in my app. I have video sized for retina 2x of a small character, so it's approx 150px square for a 75px character, with alpha/transparency. My animator can output any common format. I'll have 50-100 frames. I do not need a power-of-two size output, any rectangle is ok. I'm working on MacOS.

Is the best workflow still: video -> folder with PNGs -> TexturePacker

Or is there any smarter way to do this? I'll be having a lot of iterations, so I'd like to make it as easy and fast as possible.

There are two older questions from [2010](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/4387/tips-and-tools-for-creating-spritesheet-animations) and [2012](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/27214/is-there-a-tool-to-make-a-spritesheet-out-of-1000-pngs) about making sprite sheets.

Comment: As a general guideline, workflow operations should be doable with a single command, like "make sprites" (run by a makefile) "ant sprites" or part of an Xcode or Visual Studio target. If you're doing more than a click or two to build your project, there's much opportunity for error.

Comment: Do you know of a way that we can include a movie file in our Xcode project, have it processed into a sprite sheet, in preparation for compiling -- i.e., so we don't process the video by the actual consumer's running app?

Comment: Ideally, texture packer has a command-line invocation that you can run in a script phase...

Can also look for a command-line tool called "qt_proofsheet" which can decompose a movie to a single-sheet of frames. (Disclosure -- I wrote it. Works last time I tried it...) http://www.omino.com/sw/qt_tools/

Comment: qt_proofsheet looks perfect. At a quick glance, I can set --framesize=150 --framesperrow=10  for my needs? and it would generate 1500 px wide, and however high it needs for all the frames within --duration=end-time ? ... QUESTION: Can it handle alpha/transparency?

Comment: I confess: I don't know what it does with alpha, never tried it. I think there's also something to do with borders/margins to set to 0.